# Why link underline is not appearing in the site pages

Tags: css, firebug, dreamweaver

This sample page:http://www.downloadformsindia.com/Income-Tax-Forms/challan-281.html?task=view has H1 text of "Challan 281". But it's not getting underlined.
In Firefox I'm right clicking and using "inspect" using firebug.

It's showing a **crossed** circle with:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #135CAE;
}
```

It means it's overriden. But how do I find out which other rule is overriding it? I'm not able to find out using even Chrome->Inspect.
Does even Dreamweaver let us find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template.css on line 23:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Will style the link without an underline.

For what it's worth, I used Chrome's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

On the element.